# Unable to select multiple images from Android gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I am unable to select multiple media from the Android gallery even after using the `Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`. I can select multiple media from the photos app.

Is there a way that I can do from the gallery app as well?

Comment: please post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is from **API 18**. So you have to do code of manual selection for lower version too. It's better to do it manually for all. For this you can refer [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/) .

One of the good [libraries](https://github.com/yazeed44/MultiImagePicker) for this.

Comment: Thank you Sanket. Even from API 18 Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE is not working. But anyhow it is good to write our own activity and the reference you provided helps.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do it using Intent.** It is available only from **API 18**. So What i suggest you use any library for **custom gallery.**

https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick
https://github.com/giljulio/android-multiple-image-picker

Comment: I'm unable to select in Android 9 also. Only some phones are having this problem.